# Must declare the scalar variable "@Modifier"

Tags: sql, .net

I have been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong for a few hours now. I am trying to add a record to my database but I am not able to do so because of the error I am getting that reads "Must declare the scalar variable "@Modifier"." I noticed other people with similar issues but I couldn't apply the same fixes to my code.

```
    Dim dbConnection As SqlConnection = connectToDb()
    Dim sqlString As String

    If currentWeapon.Id > 0 Then
        sqlString = "Update Weapons Set Name = @name"
    Else
        sqlString = "INSERT INTO Weapons (Name, APPower, HEPower, Range, Modifier) VALUES(@name, @APPower, @HEPower, @Range, @Modifier)"
        lastWeaponId += 1
        currentWeapon.Id = lastWeaponId
    End If

    Dim com As New SqlCommand(sqlString, dbConnection)

    com.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = currentWeapon.Name
    com.Parameters.Add("@APPower", SqlDbType.Int).Value = currentWeapon.APPower
    com.Parameters.Add("@HEPower", SqlDbType.Int).Value = currentWeapon.HEPower
    com.Parameters.Add("@Range", SqlDbType.Int).Value = currentWeapon.Range
    com.Parameters.Add("@Modifer", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = currentWeapon.Modifier


    Try
        Dim result = com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `@Modifer` instead of `@Modifier`

```
com.Parameters.Add("@Modifer", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = currentWeapon.Modifier
                          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:  `@Modifer` vs. `@Modifier`.

In your query, you use `@Modifier`:

```
"INSERT INTO Weapons (Name, APPower, HEPower, Range, Modifier) 
VALUES(@name, @APPower, @HEPower, @Range, @Modifier)"
```

But you specify the parameter name on the command as `@Modifer`:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@Modifer", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = currentWeapon.Modifier
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the catch, I've been at this all night and I guess I am not thinking the best at 6AM lol.

Comment: You're welcome.  Actually Koby beat me to it by 11 seconds so if you want to award the answer, you should award it to his.